# NHibernate - Cannot set the ConfigurationCache property after calling Init

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-3, s#arp-architecture

In my S#arp Arch 2.0 project, I'm communicating with 2 databases. This runs fine locally with the ASP.Net Development Server (VS 2010) and passes unit tests requiring talking to either database.

Next step was to Publish the project (using VS' built-in "Publish" menu option) to the in-house development server (Windows Server 2008 R2) and fire this thing up on a real server where people could actually see it.

Now I get the exception shown in the title when I try to run the application. The exception is thrown at the = new NHibernateConfigurationFileCache() line below:

```
private void InitialiseNHibernateSessions()
    {
        NHibernateSession.ConfigurationCache = new NHibernateConfigurationFileCache();

        NHibernateSession.InitStorage(this.webSessionStorage);

        NHibernateSession.AddConfiguration(NHibernateSession.DefaultFactoryKey,
            new[] { Server.MapPath("~/bin/SRN2.Infrastructure.dll") },
            new AutoPersistenceModelGenerator().Generate(),
            Server.MapPath("~/NHibernate.config"),
            null, null, null);


        NHibernateSession.AddConfiguration(SRN2.Infrastructure.DataGlobals.OTHER_DB_FACTORY_KEY,
            new string[] { Server.MapPath("~/bin/SRN2.Infrastructure.dll") },
            new AutoPersistenceModelGenerator().Generate(),
            Server.MapPath("~/NHibernate-OTHER.config"),
            null, null, null);

    }
```

Stack trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Cannot set the ConfigurationCache property after calling Init]
   SharpArch.NHibernate.NHibernateSession.set_ConfigurationCache(INHibernateConfigurationCache value) +105
   SRN2.Web.Mvc.MvcApplication.InitialiseNHibernateSessions() in C:\code\SRN2-Sharp2\trunk\Solutions\SRN2.Web.Mvc\Global.asax.cs:122
   SharpArch.NHibernate.NHibernateInitializer.InitializeNHibernateOnce(Action initMethod) +116
   SRN2.Web.Mvc.MvcApplication.Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) in     C:\code\SRN2-Sharp2\trunk\Solutions\SRN2.Web.Mvc\Global.asax.cs:71
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +148
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286594/nhibernate-iis7-5-throws-a-session-factory-has-already-been-configured-with-th/7287521#7287521

Comment: I don't see what that's doing any differently than this, except for wrapping it in a try/catch, and the catch just throws the exception, so that's not going to fix anything...

Comment: Not sure of the answer, but it looks like your InitialiseNHibernateSessions method is being called multiple times. I'd suggest the first step would be to get the site running under IIS or IIS Express in your dev environment and reproduce the error - the ASP.NET development server has "a number of architectural differences" (Microsoft's words) from IIS, so you can't rely on getting the same behaviour as you will in a production environment. Try and get a local repro working and see what clues that gives you - then let us know :-)

Comment: I don't have admin privs locally (ironic that I should have more privs on the VMs but I don't make policy) so running under IIS locally is going to be difficult.

Comment: Any other suggestions? I can waste 4 hours setting up a VM to run IIS and try it that way, but if there's anything else I can try first, I'm more inclined to do that.

Comment: Can you do IIS Express instead? It's much closer in terms of architecture to IIS, and you don't need admin permissions to run it.

Comment: Alternatively, if you can remove non-essential code and create a project that reproduces the issue, I'm happy to take a look at it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jon is right, it does sound like your InitialiseNHibernateSessions method is being called multiple times. You don't have to use the config cache, have you tried disabling it?

The NHibernate configuration is cached to file in order to improve start up time. If the configuration has not changed it is loaded from the cache file. The default location of the cache file is the system temporary file folder (e.g. Path.GetTempPath()).

If you don't have file permissions, or don't need config caching, just remove or comment out the line that initialises the configuration cache, i.e. this line:

```
NHibernateSession.ConfigurationCache = new NHibernateConfigurationFileCache();
```

Comment: Well, disabling the cache worked. I assume this is only going to be a minor performance hit, and only when the app pool is recycled? I'll see if I can figure out what the path was that it was trying to use and see if the INET_USR has bad permissions for it.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurred, for one application, roughly every month or two months for an extended period. I haven't really been able to fix this permanently but I did discover that the following procedure resolves the error for:

1. Delete the temporary configuration cache files; they should be located in the Windows temporary files folder and there should be a file for each database (e.g. *DatabaseName--1973822310.bin*) and another named something like *nhibernate.current_session--1973822310.bin*.
2. Restart the IIS web site for your application.
3. Recycle the application pool for your application.